# How to convert JavaRDD<List<String>> to JavaRDD<String> and write to a file without "[" and "]"

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a `JavaRDD<List<String>>` and my file is getting written with [] at the beginning and end of each list of strings when I use

```java
javacontext.parallelize(rdd).coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile("dirname");
```

Can we convert `JavaRDD<List<String>>` to `JavaRDD<String>` and write it to a file?

Comment: How did you create the `rdd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `map` to apply `String.join` for each `List<String>` in `JavaRDD`:

```java
String separator = ",";
JavaRDD<String> ys = rdd
        .map(new Function<List<String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(List<String> xs) throws Exception {
                return String.join(separator, xs);
            }
        });
```

Or using lambdas:

```java
JavaRDD<String> ys = rdd
        .map((Function<List<String>, String>) xs -> String.join(separator, xs));
```